# Read XML data from an rss file

Tags: javascript, xml, rss

say i have an rss feed, that i want to get data from- picassa specifically- which uses atom i suppose.

i want to be able to parse this rss file as xml file getElements/etc

im aware that reading it directly and manipulating probably wont work as it get some access cross domain error, so ive simply downloaded the file and hosted it on my own domain-(also is there any way to allow chrome to view xml data locally- it seems to think its cross server even when its viewed locally which makes preview editing a pain)

i cant seem to read the data properly through traditional means and searching appears to give severely outdated information

Answer (score 0):

Go take a look at the YAHOO-PIPES service, it's free and easy to use. This will allow you to extract any information you need from an RSS feed and send the results to a server in JSON format if you require.